# boost atomic class make initialize values different from member initialization list

Tags: c++, boost, initialization, atomic

I use firstly boost::atomic class and there is a initialize problem.

I have a RowActiveData struct

```
struct RowActiveData {
    RowActiveData() : _rowActive(0), _rowActiveFile(0), _rowActiveTrack(1)
    {}
    size_t    _rowActive;
    size_t    _rowActiveFile;
    size_t    _rowActiveTrack;
};
```

and there is RowActive struct use it.

```
struct IRowActive {
    virtual void setRowActive(size_t row) = 0;
};

struct RowActive : public IRowActive {
    RowActive() {}

    virtual void setRowActive(size_t row)
    {
        RowActiveData tmpData;
        tmpData._rowActive = row;

        tmpData._rowActiveFile = row * 2;
        tmpData._rowActiveTrack = row * 3;
    }

//    boost::atomic
//        <RowActiveData>      _data;
    RowActiveData            _data;
};
```

When my process is run, I see everything is fine. 
It gives me the values as I expected.

```
_rowActiveFile is 0 and _rowActiveTrack is 1.
```

But when I comment out

```
// RowActiveData _data;
```

and remove atomic comment out

```
boost::atomic <RowActiveData> _data;
```

it gives me garbage values.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a simplified full program demonstrating this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the boost documentation, the empty constrcutor initializes to an *unspecified* value. Try

```
boost::atomic<RowActiveData> _data(RowActiveData());
```

Boost docs are at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/atomic/interface.html

Also, I've checked, and it seems to me that at least the boost implementation in http://www.chaoticmind.net/~hcb/projects/boost.atomic/ would use a char array member instead of RowActiveData, therefore not calling the constructor.

Comment: Thank you, it works with it. Now I tried to initialize in RowActive constructor MIL. But I still don't understand why RowActiveData constructor is worked and I get garbage value. I mean before the correction RowActiveData's constructor is called.

Comment: never mind, maybe I saw different object's constructor and I am mistaken.